# Fast subsetting in Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, indexing, subset

I am running a loop a few million times, and I need to subset a different amount of data in each loop. I have a dataframe that has two columns, time (which is a time series) and electrode, which signifies a number between 1-64 for any electrode fired at that time.

```
time    electrode
 0          1
 1          43
 2          45
 3          12
 4          7
```

In each loop I need to subset the data, as such:

```
num_electrodes = []
window_size = 5
index = 0
while index < len(data['time']) - interval_size:
    start = data['time'][index]
    end = data['time'][index+window_size]
    window_data = data[(data['time'] >= start) & (data['time'] < end)]
    num_electrodes.append(len(window_data['electrode'].unique()))
```

The really slow part of the code here is subsetting the dataframe and making a new dataframe, in the following code.

```
window_data = data[(data['time'] >= start) & (data['time'] < end)]
```

Is there any good alternative to this?

Comment: Is your `time` series string / `datetime` / `timedelta` / something else?

Comment: When do you augment index and from how many?

Comment: @jpp the data is normalized to start at timepoint '0' and then continues to timepoint ~3600 minutes, with increments of ~0.001 minutes.

Comment: @B.M. i actually put a simplified example here, i just want to know how to faster subset my data

Answer (score 1):

Sort by your time, then you can use .loc to access the indices at the beginning and end of your window, and then select a range of indices as your subset.

Set your df's index to the time series, then use `df.index.get_loc(beginning_window)` and `min(df.index.get_loc(beginning_window+window+1)) -1` to get your index range.

The min accounts for non-unique indices.

Then use .iloc to select that range.

That should speed it up by quite a bit.

Comment: i will try this... the problem is i am not only choosing index + 5 as i gave in this example, but need to find the end of the window based on the actual time value, so this involves finding the index of this time point

Comment: You can find the index of that time, once you set your index to the time column by using df.index.get_loc(time).

Comment: i don't know the specific time though, i need to find the last time within the time window, then find the index. and to make things more complicated, more than one electrode can fire at the same time, so the times are not unique values

Comment: if you don't know where you want to start your window, no one else can help you determine that. choose randomly or go through every possibility. updated the answer to accommodate non-unique indices

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this by switching to numpy.ndarray which just went infinitely faster than indexing with iloc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is sorted by time, you just have to group the electrodes by 5.  Then `set` can be faster than `np.unique` :

```
size=10**6
window_size=5
electrodes = np.random.randint(0,64,size)
electrodes_by_5 = electrodes.reshape(-1,window_size)

nb_electrodes=np.apply_along_axis(lambda arr:len(set(arr)),1,electrodes_by_5)
```

Output :

```
In [463]: electrodes[:10]
Out[463]: array([13, 13, 23, 20,  5, 30,  9,  6, 28, 11])

In [464]: electrodes_by_5[:2]
Out[464]: 
array([[13, 13, 23, 20,  5],
       [30,  9,  6, 28, 11]])

In [465]: nb_electrodes[:2]
Out[465]: array([4, 5])
```